# A specific way of getting neutral narration endings?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

There are 12 endings - 3 different narrations for each of the 4 choices... What exactly changes this?

Killing enemies? How many do you need to kill to get the neutral ending? What about "innocents"? Notable NPCs?

How do the quests factor into this (saving people, defusing the bomb near the start)? Dialogue? Does being an a****** factor into this?

I already got the good narrations, so you can drop spoilers here and there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four separate endings based on what you choose at the end:

- "It was something in the water": follow Bill Taggart's ending and cover up the truth, blaming Neuropozyne poisoning as the reason for everything that happened
- "Terrorists did it": follow David Sarif's request and blame Humanity Front
- "I want to believe": follow Hugh Darrrow's request and reveal the truth about what happened to the public
- "The truth is out there": blow it all up by activating the self destruct mechanism aboard Panchaea

Additionally, the narration changes based on how you played the game:

- Evil ending: If you murdered everybody, Jensen will talk about abuse of power
- Neutral ending: If you killed a few people, Jensen will talk about how he tried to do the right thing
- Good ending: If you succeeded at pacifist, Jensen will talk about how the detractors of transhumanisation are wrong in their beliefs

If you're specifically after the neutral endings, don't go crazy with killing people. I'm not sure there are any actual figures available for how many people you have to kill before you're classified as evil, but not purposely going out and murdering everything I saw was how I got the neutral endings.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've got neutral ending after killing every killable NPC I've found, except for 'has to survive' quest-related NPCs, which I've killed after receiving quest reward.

Maybe my methods were wrong? I've mostly gone delicate takedown to get 'merciful soul' and keep quiet, then nailed 'em with silenced pistol. For me it's a really evil playthrough.

Or maybe being bad in-quest boy is required to become indepth evil?